# MEAN stack - replace document field array id's with corresponding name from another collection

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have two collections with following data format -

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5b336305fa012c47c837d3b9"),
   "title":"Information",
   "description":"<p><strong>Hello World! This is a test editor</strong></p>",
   "status":"publish",
   "categories":[  
      "5b2b02cd317c7e100d3ae773"
   ],
   "created_date":   ISODate("2018-06-27T10:12:21.294   Z"),
   "image":"/articles/server/images/1530094341293.jpg",
   "owner_id":"5b1510af1d1b700edc110dda"
}


{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5b2b02cd317c7e100d3ae773"),
   "name":"Google",
   "slug":"google_1529545421927",
   "description":"google another test....",
   "created_date":   ISODate("2018-06-21T01:43:41.918   Z")
}
```

First one is `Articles` and second one is `Categories` collection.

What I have been trying is to replace following `Articles` collection field id's with corresponding category name from `Categories` collection when my express request response back with `json` data -

```
"categories":[  
          "5b2b02cd317c7e100d3ae773"
       ],
```

So I would be able to send category name rather than id in following format -

```
"categories":[  
              "Google"
           ],
```

I have been trying with `forEach` of `MongoDB` query with following code -

```
db.collection('articles').find()
            .forEach(function (article) {
                let categories = article.categories;

                categories = categories.map(id => ObjectID(id));

                var doc2 = db.collection('categories').find({_id: {$in: categories}});

                console.log(doc2);

                res.status(200).json('success');

            });
```

I appreciate your any hints or solution to get efficient solution without writing so much query.

**Note:**

I tried with `aggregate $lookup` but I could not able to do that as I have to deal with `array` rather than a value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` - it's not that hard to deal with those arrays.

```
db.collection('articles').aggregate([
    // {_id: '...', categories: ['...', '...', ...]}
    {$project: {categories: 1}},

    // {_id: '...', categories: '...'}
    {$unwind: '$categories'},

    // {_id: '...', categories: [{_id: '...', name: '...', ...}, ...]}
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'categories',
        localField: 'categories',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'categories'
    }},

    // {_id: '...', categories: {_id: '...', name: '...', ...}}
    {$unwind: '$categories'},

    // {_id: '...', categories: ['...', ...]}
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id', 
        categories: {$addToSet: '$categories.name'}
    }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b336305fa012c47c837d3b9"),
    "categories" : [ 
        "Google"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Looks like it's pretty workable but still doesn't work. Returns empty array but collection has documents. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: I made a debug. `$unwind` second time doesn't work. So when I skip adding `$unwind` for second time, I get following data - `[ 
     { _id: 5b336d71214cc14adca7342c, categories: [Array] },{},{}...]`

Comment: So the id in categories is a string, not an ObjectId. In this case, you can use [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/#exp._S_toObjectId) from Mongo 4. I don’t see any option for older versions than calling find twice and cast these ids manually.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I replaced categories array's string to ObjectId. My current MongoDB version is 3.6.5 so converting string to ObjectId is bit tricky(according to your last comment) as I can't use `$toObjectId`. Thank you very much!